# How to add to a string value of a property instead of rewriting it in Cypher Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose I make a request in Neo4J (3.5) Cypher and I want to rewrite the last letter of the value in the property of a node rather than rewriting it.

I do add a string with the following request, but how to replace the last letter "a" for example with "o" and then add the string after?

```
MATCH (c:Context{name:'lisaksa'}) WITH c.name AS cname, c SET c.name = cname + '_new';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MATCH (c:Context{name:'lisaksa'}) 
SET c.name = left(c.name,size(c.name)-1) + 'o'+'_new'
```